# Compare a particular field value fom textfield to mysql column value where one value is fixed

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, authentication

This is the code I'm  using innetbeans with mysql db.

The form is accepting user input(name and password) and successfully inserting it to the db table.

But when I'm trying to login into the form using the name and password where keeping the name fixed I want to compare the password and if the password field match for the particular name then only to login .

This is showing Exception:

> Exception:Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'

I'm saving the password as sting in my db table but using the JPasswordField while taking input from user.

```
public class Trying extends JFrame{
Trying(){
   //declaration of fields and buttons
    // adding name and password in mysql table
    jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "root", "");
                String query="INSERT INTO tryingtable (name,password) VALUES (?,?)";
                PreparedStatement prepstmt=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                prepstmt.setString(1, jtf.getText());
                char[] password = jpf.getPassword();
                String pass = new String(password);
                prepstmt.setString(2,pass);
                prepstmt.execute();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");
                prepstmt.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception on submit:"+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    // user will enter passsword and name and we will check in mysql table if the password in correct for the particular name in mysql table
    jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","");
                String query="SELECT password FROM tryingtable WHERE name=?;";
                PreparedStatement prepstmt=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                prepstmt.setString(1,jtf.getText());
                ResultSet rs=prepstmt.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()){
                    String result=rs.getString(query);
                    char[] pass = jpf.getPassword();
                    String password1= Arrays.toString(pass);
                    if(result.equals(password1)){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "logged in");}
                    else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry");}
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception:"+e.getMessage());
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Trying();
}

}
```

Please help to to successfully compare the password fields while the name is fixed.

Comment: You are using 2 different table names, `tryingtable` and `trytable`

Comment: @LorisSecuro Sorry my fault both the tabls are same tryingtable. Please check if the code is working are comparing the password .

Answer (score 1):

`String result=rs.getString(query);` is not correct. You are passing the whole query to the method.

You should instead pass the [column name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString-java.lang.String-) or the [index number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString-int-) of the column you want to retrieve:

```
String result = rs.getString("password");
```

or

```
String result = rs.getString(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

@LorisSecuro is absolutely correct : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51609437/10123626
In addtion to that what you need to change in the above code is :

> > when you want to compare password field to textfield use

```
char[] pass_char = passwordField.getPassword();
String pass_string = new String(pass_char);
```

> > Above code will give you your password field value in string form, then

```
if(pass_string.equals(textfield))
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Password match");
else
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Password did not match");
```